# Intellectual Property Rights Policy Summary Question

Tags: customization, distro-recommendation, policy

In the Summary section, this is stated, "You can redistribute Ubuntu, but only where there has been no modification to it." What does it mean by Mortifications? Does it mean Kernel/Internal Modifications, or Program/Desktop Environment Modifications?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27450/discussion-on-question-by-awlsomealex-intellectual-property-rights-policy-summar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracted from the comment conversation and my comments:

You are asking whether you can use Ubuntu's repos on your derivative and then give this new OS to others.

According to this, you can:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeDistroHowto/#Usage_of_Ubuntu_servers_as_sources_of_binary_packages